# Odata filter query does not work for person field DisplayName

Tags: odata, power-automate, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have created a Power Automate flow for my Power App to export all values based on the `SLT_Name`. I want the users to be able to filter the records by partially entering the SLT_Owner's name.
SLT_Owner is of type person.
[image: Here is how my flow looks like]

```
ExportRows.Run("substringof('"& SLT_Owner_Filter_txt.Text &"',SLT_Owner/DisplayName)",User().Email);
```

This returns zero results. But it works when I say `SLT_Owner/DisplayName eq '[Name]'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint person or group columns has `Title` property and not `DisplayName`, while working with filter queries of "Get items" action in Power Automate.

So, try using query in this format:

```
substringof('Ganesh',PersonColumn/Title)
```

REST API example:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')/items?$select=Title,PersonColumn/Title&$expand=PersonColumn&$filter=substringof('Ganesh',PersonColumn/Title)
```

Where `PersonColumn` is an **internal name** of your column in SharePoint list. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Isn't the below script the way we save values for person field in PowerApps?
{'@odata.type':"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",

        Claims:"i:0#.f|membership|michael@wiXXXX.onmicrosoft.com",

    Department:"",

   DisplayName:"Michael Shao",
         Email:"Michael@wiXXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
      JobTitle:"",
       Picture:""
   }

Comment: Yes, it is. However, Get items action in Power automate uses SharePoint REST API behind the scene. And filter queries with SharePoint REST API works as I mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me big time. Dealing with PowerApps is very tricky. Not sure why Microsoft is using different attributes for PowerApps and Sharepoint